# C++ How to hard code name into binary

Tags: c++, binary

I have a project that I am working on and I currently have it working to enter my name > then it converts to hex > encrypts it > decrypts it > then prints it.  The problem is I need to hard code my name in binary instead of how it currently works.  I have no idea how to convert it.

Here is the code snippet.
I apologize if I have entered the code wrong.  First time posting.

```
CfinalprAES ofinalprAES;
ofinalprAES.MakeKey("abcdefghabcdefgh", "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16, 16);
char szDataIn[80];

printf("Enter your Name: ");
scanf("%79s", szDataIn);

char szDataOut[17] = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
ofinalprAES.EncryptBlock(szDataIn, szDataOut);
CharStr2HexStr((unsigned char*)szDataIn, szHex, 16);
printf("Hex of input: ");
cout << szHex << endl;
CharStr2HexStr((unsigned char*)szDataOut, szHex, 16);
printf("Encrypted: ");
cout << szHex << endl;
memset(szDataIn, 0, 16);
ofinalprAES.DecryptBlock(szDataOut, szDataIn);
CharStr2HexStr((unsigned char*)szDataIn, szHex, 16);
printf("Decrypted: ");
std::stringstream ss;
ss << szHex << endl;
printf("Hex to String: ");
cout << ss.str();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hard code" and "binary"?

Comment: You can simply use `char szDataIn[] = "Chris Bertsch";` to hard-code your name in your binary (executable).  Is that what you're after?

Comment: There is no difference between `char` and binary. a plain dictionary: char - each character represented by a single symbol, or it numeric ASCII value  (for ASCII characters), not all symbol are seen. hex - each character represented by it value, when the value contain 2 hexadecimal digits. by translating to hex string you also convert binary file to text file.

Comment: Mike Seymour binary as in the executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple hard coding:

```
char szDataIn[80] = "Chris Bertsch";
```

If you want to make that a little bit more obfuscated, you can use hex representations of the characters in your name:

```
char szDataIn[80] = "\x43\x68\x72\x69\x73\x20\x42\x65\x72\x74\x73\x63\x68";
```

Comment: Truly hard coding should make it a `static const char`.  Remember that literals are read-only.  The `const` should also place it into an array.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, `szDataIn` is an array. I don't understand how use of `static const` is better for hard coding.

Comment: @RSahu: For example: `static const char Input_Data[] = "Chris Bertsch";`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I didn't mean the syntax. How is it conceptually better?